# How to disable global handlers like ajaxStart or ajaxStop from being triggered for catcomplete?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-blockui

While using  jQuery BlockUI Plugin for ajax loading with the given code:

```
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

shows ajax loading of BlockUI for each search character using autocomplete and catcomplete. In this case how to prevent global handlers so that ajax loading of BlockUI do not appear.

I have the of following code for my autocomplete:

```
$("#query").catcomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: "/searches/auto_complete",
        appendTo: "#identifier",
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var query_value = $("#query").val(ui.item.label);
            query_value = $.trim(query_value);
            $("#query").val(query_value);
            $("#search_id").val(ui.item.search_id);
            $("#from").val(ui.item.from);
            $(".search-form").submit();
        }

    });
```

Comment: I'm guessing you can't, that's sort of the point of global handlers, they always fire.

Answer (score 0):

@adeneo Finally got a solution to this. We should set global: false . Here is the complete solution.

```
$("#query").catcomplete({
        appendTo: "#identifier",
        source: function (request, response)
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                global: false,
                minLength: 3,
                source: "/searches/auto_complete",
                url: "/searches/auto_complete",
                dataType: "json",
                data:
                {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function (data)
                {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var query_value = $("#query").val(ui.item.label);
            query_value = $.trim(query_value);
            $("#query").val(query_value);
            $(".search-form").submit();
        }

    });
```